# sending data as an array but receiving it as [object Object]

Tags: typescript

Hi In my stencil application I  have created a component which receives data as an array as well JSON.stringfiied like below:

```
<myComponent :data=[1,2,3,4] />
<myComponent :data="JSON.stringify([1,2,3,4])" />
```

in my stencil component it receives as [object Object], However it should be read as Array. Here is snapshot of stenciljs @prop part

```
 @Prop() data: string | Array<Record<'type' | 'value' | 'percentage', string>>;
```

User can send stringified (using JSON.stringify as well as directly can send  an array to the component.)

I want to cactch up both. but if I send array as an input to web component it received as [object Object]

Comment: Arrays in Javascript are objects.  They are a special type of object.  I’m not familiar with the stencil package so I don’t know for certain what’s going on here, but this type definition `string | Array<Record<'type' | 'value' | 'percentage', string>>` is saying that `data` can only be a string or an array of a specific type of object (`Record<'type' | 'value' | 'percentage', string>`).  I think what’s happening is that your array of numbers doesn’t fit that definition, so it’s getting converted to a string.  And since arrays are objects, you are getting the string `”[object Object]” `.

Comment: Array<any> does not work even..

Comment: Can you post a link to a demo (codesandbox, stackblitz, etc.) or a repo?